# How to change contact thumbnail picture in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to change contact thumbnail picture from my app. The `Contact` class has a property `Thumbnail` which is settable as hints me a intellisense:

> "Gets or sets a thumbnail image that represents this contact"

In my app there is a grid control which contains some image. Also there is a simple button clicking on which will open contact picker and after selecting the contact app will change the thumbnail image of picked contact.
First of all I have a method which rendering and saving image from the grid to the file system:

```
private async Task SaveImage()
{
    var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(this.IconGrid);
    var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

    var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight, 96d, 96d, pixelBuffer.ToArray());

        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

This method works perfectly and saves the image as it need to do.
And here is a method responsible for picking contact and changing thumbnail image:

```
private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContactPicker contactPicker = new ContactPicker();
    contactPicker.CommitButtonText = "Select";
    contactPicker.SelectionMode = ContactSelectionMode.Contacts;

    await SaveImage();
    var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("test.png");
    Contact contact = await contactPicker.PickContactAsync();
    contact.Thumbnail = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(file);           
}
```

Above method works without any exception. But as a result the contact picture is not changed, it remains the old one. I also tried set image from `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` without saving it on a hard drive, but the result is same

So how I can modify my code to be able to change contact picture ?